# In DolphinDB, how to deal with mutable arguments in a concise way?

Tags: parameters, parameter-passing, dolphindb

In the function `makeCall(F, args...)`, *args* are the required arguments of *F*. When *F* involves multiple arguments, I currently use the `if-else` statement and write the `makeCall` function as follows to determine the number of arguments:

`makeCall(f1,sqlCol(args[0]))`, or

`makeCall(f2,sqlCol(args[0]),sqlCol(args[1]))`, or

`makeCall(f3,sqlCol(args[0]),sqlCol(args[1]),sqlCol(args[2]))`.

However, as the number of arguments in *F* increases, the script becomes lengthy due to the increasing number of `if-else` statements. Is there a concise way to pass the arguments in *args* to the `makeCall` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `makeUnifiedCall` function which encapsulates all input arguments into a tuple, so that you don't need to worry about the number of arguments. When passing arguments, you can initialize a tuple for *args* of `makeUnifiedCall` as follows (*param* for example) and use `append!` to add arguments.

```
param = []
param.append!(x)
param.append!(y)
```